# Maps on Riemannian manifold agreeing with geodesics

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $(M, g)$ be an $n$-dimensional smooth Riemannian manifold. Let
$$ \Gamma_n = \{ [0,1] \ni t \mapsto \gamma_x^y(t) = (1-t)x + ty \mid x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n \}.$$
Let us choose $m \in M$. Can we always choose a map $\phi \colon U \to \mathbb{R}^n$, where $U$ is a neighbourhood of $m$ such that:

- $\phi [U]$ is convex
- for all $x, y \in \phi[U]$ the element $\gamma_x^y \in \Gamma_n$ satisfies: $\phi^{-1} \circ \gamma_x^y$ is a geodesic in $M$?

Comment: Don't you want $\phi$ to be a a diffeomorphism? If so, then you are asking whether there is a diffeomorphism that takes geodesics to lines (and vice versa). This *requires* $M$ to have constant curvature. (Essentially, this is a result of Cartan and Hadamard in dimension $\geq 3$ and of Blaschke in dimension 2.)

Comment: Yes, though, if possible, could you provide me with a reference to the result you mention? I tried to find it and I mostly find the Cartan-Hadamard theorem regarding the complete Riemannian manifolds with non-positive sectional curvature.  

Also, if that changes anything, I only want to map line segments from some neighbourhood to geodesics defined on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Your condition is that the projective connection induced from the Levi-Civita connection is flat. You can probably find a proof of this in Projective Differential Geometry Old and New by Tabachnikov and Ovsienko.

Comment: I believe OP is trying to get clarification on where constant curvature of the metric comes in

Comment: One (somewhat convoluted) proof of the result for dimension $\geq 3$ can be found [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.583.4721&rep=rep1&type=pdf) on pages 12-13. The proof for dimension 2 is perhaps in [the book by Sharpe](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387947327#aboutBook); as Ben McKay has said it is about projectively flat connections.

Comment: Actually, I believe that the original proof that there is a local coordinate system in which the geodesics are straight lines if and only if the Gauss curvature is constant is due to Beltrami.  The proof in higher dimensions follows immediately from the proof in dimension $2$.  For a straightforward elementary proof in dimension $2$, you can see Exercise 13 in Chapter 4, Section 6 of do Carmo's *Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces*.